# Integrability conditions imply existence of potential

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, differential-equations

I'm looking for a proof of the following well-known theorem:

> If $f$ is a continuously differentiable vector field in a simply connected region $G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which satisfies the integrability conditions, then there is potential $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi = f$.

I know a proof for star-shaped regions. By googling I also found proofs for $n=2$ (resp. $n=3$) which make use of the theorem of Green (resp. Stokes).

**Question 1:** Does someone know a reference where a proof of the general case is written down?

**Question 2:** Can simply-connected be weakened in $H^1(G)=0$?

Comment: I upvoted your question since in my experience, for these well known theorems, references to rigorous yet sufficiently general proofs can sometimes be hard to find: of course other members may freely show that I'm wrong, but if it will be so, it will always be a good thing.

Comment: Is it important to you that $f\in C^1$ and not $C^\infty$? In the latter case I think you can find a proof in Madsen & Tornehave (not sure, since my copy is in my office to which I haven't been for ... quite a while).